# Motives up to homological equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, hodge-theory, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$ finitely generated over its prime field, and $M_{hom}(X)$ the category of motives modulo $\ell$-adic homological equivalence.

> (1) Is $M_{hom}(X)$ an **abelian category** (ie. provably)?

**Assume now the semi-simplicity conjecture**, ie. the statement that the action of $\text{Gal}(k^{\rm sep}/k)$ on $\ell$-adic étale cohomology of $X_{k^{\rm sep}}$ is semi-simple.

> (2) Is, then, $M_{hom}(X)$ a **semi-simple abelian** category?

**References.** Y. André, *Pour une théorie inconditionelle de motifs*. IHES. in case you want to refresh the definition of $M_{hom}(X)$ (see around $\S$1.2).

Comment: What is the coefficient ring?  Modules over $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ do not form a semisimple Abelian category.  Are you tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$?

Comment: Yes, I am! And $\ell$-adic cohomology is supposed to be rational $\ell$-adic cohomology in my question.

Comment: Jannsen has shown (https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/26642/1/jannsen10.pdf) that numerical equivalence is the *only* adequate equivalence relation on algebraic cycles such that the resulting category of motives is semisimple abelian. In particular, if $M_{\mathrm{hom}}$ were semisimple abelian then homological equivalence would have to coincide with numerical equivalence, which is Grothendieck's standard conjecture D. (This doesn't answer your question per se, but it might be relevant.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I think the OP had precisely the intention of asking if the semisimplicity conjecture implies Grothendieck’s conjecture D.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not known over any field and for any cohomology theory whether homological motives form an abelian category. For example, if $X \to Y$ is a morphism of varieties, we have no way to construct kernels or cokernels for $H^i(Y) \to H^i(X)$. Very little is known in this direction.

Comment: OK. Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I find the reference to Jannsen's paper also quite interesting. Thanks!

Comment: If the category of motives for homological equivalence is abelian and the gradations on the cohomology arise from gradations on the motive, then hom=num. See the Appendix to Andre 1996 (IHES).